# Can an upper endoscopy spot gallbladder problems?

Tags: gallbladder

Something of a followup to [a previous question I asked](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/can-ulcer-pain-be-distinguished-from-gallstone-pain):

Is an upper endoscopy (esophagogastroduodenoscopy or EGD) able to spot gallbladder problems? I have not really found a consistent answer in a few sources I looked at:

- [MUSC Health: Upper Endoscopy (EGD)](http://www.ddc.musc.edu/public/procedures/upperEndoscopy.html) makes no mention of gallbladder
- [What is EUS?](http://www.cig-pc.com/faqs.htm) says an EUS, endoscopic ultrasound, is needed
- [ASGE](http://www.asge.org/press/press.aspx?id=548) suggests that a specialized endoscopy (Endoscopic retrograde cholangiopancreatography (ERCP)) might work (but that seems more complex than an EGD)

However, an upper endoscopy does take a peek at the duodenum. Would there be signs of gallbladder problems there, or not?